# while adding background image in circle Avatar from Assetsimage got an error ? how to fixed it

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

PlatformAssetBundle.load (package:flutter/src/services/asset_bundle.dart:224:7)

#1      AssetBundleImageProvider._loadAsync (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:672:14)

Image provider: AssetImage(bundle: null, name: "images/profile.png")
Image key: AssetBundleImageKey(bundle: PlatformAssetBundle#3b91a(), name: "images/profile.png",
scale: 1.0)

Comment: can you show your file structure, code and pubspec.yaml

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're indentating for assets as

```
flutter:

  assets:
    - images/profile.png
```

Comment: yes i already makes it , but still showing same error.